# Mongodb collection insert ignoring unique index

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, docker, mongoose

I have the following Image Model, built w/ mongoose, using two unique indexes:

```
'use strict';

var mongoose = require('bluebird').promisifyAll(require('mongoose'));

var Schema = new mongoose.Schema({

  name: String,
  src: { type:String, unique: true },
  height: String,
  width: String,
  importSrc: { type:String, unique: true },

  status: String,

  // Timestamps
  createdAt: Date,
  updatedAt: Date,
  deletedAt: Date
});

Schema.pre('save', function(next){
  var now = new Date();
  if ( !this.createdAt ) {
    this.createdAt = now;
  }
  this.updatedAt = now;
  next();
});

Schema.index({'importSrc':1},{ unique: true, sparse: true });

export default mongoose.model('Image', Schema);
```

As You can see, I've have tried to set up uniqueness in two different ways. However, when executing a simple insert, uniqueness is ignored, and all records are inserted.

The following is my simple insert operation:

```
var image = {
  importSrc: 'unique-url.jpg',
  src: 'whereImagesGo'
};   

Image.collection.insert(image, (err,res) => {

  if(!err && res.result.n > 0) 
    this.upload.report.image.inserts++;
  else 
    this.upload.report.image.exists++;
  complete(null);

});
```

I am currently using the official mongo docker container, which is also running mongo 3.2

Comment: Why `this.upload.report.image.exists++;` on both `if` and `else`?

Comment: @GuruprasadRao whoops! Typo! Fixed.